# copy a file omitting the first X characters

Tags: ruby, windows

I am manipulating proprietary files, which are very similar to wave files but with a custom header, longer than the wav header (200 bytes versus 36 bytes). The samples are similar though. These files are quite large (200Meg typically).

I am trying to batch convert the proprietary files to wav.

I wrote a short script using the wavefile gem. I just read the whole array of samples then create the wave file. It works fine with smaller examples but I have a memory allocation error for larger ones.

I noticed that using Fileutils.cp, copying the file is impressively fast. I am wondering if I could somehow copy the file while "omitting" the first 164 bytes, then just write the wave header in the first 36bytes and rename the file (.wav).

What would be the best/easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would likely work:

```
File.open(src, 'rb') do |r|
  File.open(dst, 'wb') do |w|
    w.write(new_dst_header)
    r.seek(200)
    until r.eof?
      w.write(r.read(chunk_size))
    end
  end
end
```

The bigger `chunk_size`, the faster it goes, and the more memory you use.